# Wrong position of the vcentered minus sign in subscript using stix2

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, stix

Is there any way to place minus sign at the same height as the horizontal bar of the plus without using raisebox?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stix2}

\begin{document}
 \( I_{a\vcenter{\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle+$}}}^{\alpha} \)

 \( I_{a\vcenter{\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle-$}}}^{\alpha} \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In my opinion, it is not good to place the minus symbol like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result is somewhat expected, because the bounding box of the minus sign is tight; in the standard Computer Modern fonts it is instead the same as for the + sign.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stix2}

\begin{document}

{\fboxrule=0.1pt\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\fbox{$-$}}

\( I_{a\vcenter{\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle+$}}}^{\alpha} \)

\( I_{a\vcenter{\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle-$}}}^{\alpha} \)

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I comment out `stix2`, I get

[image]

Solution: add `\vphantom{+}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stix2}

\begin{document}

\( I_{a\vcenter{\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle+$}}}^{\alpha} \)

\( I_{a\vcenter{\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle{-}\vphantom{+}$}}}^{\alpha} \)

\end{document}
```

[image]

A generic definition:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stix2}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\splus}{{\mathpalette\splus@minus+}}
\newcommand{\sminus}{{\mathpalette\splus@minus-}}
\newcommand{\splus@minus}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{$\m@th
    \ifx#1\displaystyle\scriptstyle\else
    \ifx#1\textstyle\scriptstyle\else
    \scriptscriptstyle\fi\fi
    \vphantom{+}{#2}$%
  }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\( a\splus \) \( a\sminus \)

\( I_{a\splus}^{\alpha} \)

\( I_{a\sminus}^{\alpha} \)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't expect that it could be connected with boxes size. Thank you very much. Your explanations are always very instructive.

Comment: Even if I don't see the author of the answer from the beautiful images of your computer I immediately understand that you are you. :-) Beautiful hat with the propeller.